# How do I determine where a variable/function was imported from?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I open up a large source file and see this:

```
print(x)
```

`x` isn't defined in this file and there are a dozen import statements. How do I determine *where* `x` was imported from?

Comment: It doesn't have zero value. It points out that that's bad. It also already prompted you to say that it's not your code, which is additional information. Although what I was really hoping for was that you'd answer the question. I.e., whether the code does indeed have such imports (clarifying whether that's likely indeed where it came from or whether it must've snuck in some other way).

Comment: Ok *now* you finally confirmed that you do have such an import. You hadn't before.

Comment: Hi @Offswitch, did any of the answers you got help you? If so you can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that your question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` is a primitive type (`int`, `float`, `complex`, `str`, `bytes`, etc.) you don't really have a good way of checking it. I guess this serves as a good reminder of avoiding things such as `from somemodule import *`.

If `x` is an object (such as a class or a function), then you can look at `x.__module__`, which will tell you the module name. There is also [`inspect.getmodule(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule) which will give you some more info (e.g. the exact path of the module).

Answer (score 1):

If it **is** a "primitive type", as Marco calls it, you could try accessing it after each import. Basic version (could be improved):

```
from fractions import *

try:
    pi
    print('fractions')
except NameError:
    pass

from math import *

try:
    pi
    print('math')
except NameError:
    pass
```

That reports `math`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P60oP1chrSgxuSQzP69YITO3IL@oREGLi6ukqNKKSwEICjIhVFFmXomGOlypuiZXakVyakGJgl9ibqprUVF@EVR9YnExFxfY3NzEkgzCRoJU4TXt/38A)

Answer (score -1):

When you import a module e.g. numpy:
import numpy as np

you can clearly see what are numpy objects or numpy methods because you can only call numpy functions for example like this np.roll(), np.array(),...

however if you dont need the full module and only a litte part of it you import it like this

from numpy import roll

now you can call the roll function simply like this:
roll()

Conclusion: If e.g. x is nowhere defined in a script it must come from an import you just need to look exactly how the module is imported

Comment: The question isn't about *how* to import. I posted a simple example but in reality, the project I'm working with imports a dozen packages, many of which, imports dozens of other packages. @Marco's answer is the correct one.